# Void method in Java | BankAccount Class Constructor

Tags: java

I need to create a void method for withdrawals that accepts a double, along with setting a balance + the amount entered parsed as a double.

I have typed this so far: public void; I am unsure how to continue.

This is the whole code that I have:

```
// Create a class named BankAccount
public class BankAccount {

    // Create a double named balance
    double balance;
    // Create a no-arg constructor named BankAccount
        // Set balance to 0.0
        public BankAccount()
        {
            balance = 0.0;
        }
        
    // Create a constructor named BankAccount that accepts a BankAccount object
        public BankAccount(double initialBalance)
        {
        
        // Set balance to the balance of the BankAccount object
        balance = initialBalance;

        }

    // Create a constructor named BankAccount that accepts a double
        // Set balance to the user's entered double
        public BankAccount(double userBalance)
        {
        balance = userBalance;
        }


    // Create a constructor named BankAccount that accepts a string
        // Set balance to the user's entered string parsed as a double
        public BankAccount(String[])
        {
            double balance = 0;
        }

    // Create a void method for deposits that accepts a double for the amount
        // Set balance to balance + the amount entered
        public void deposit(double depositAmount)
        {
        balance += double depositAmount;
        }
        

    // Create a void method for deposits that accepts a string for the amount
        // Set balance to balance + the amount entered parsed as a double
        public void deposit(String[])
        {
            balance += double depositAmount;
        }

    // Create a void method for withdrawals that accepts a double for the amount
        // Set balance to balance - the amount entered
        public void
```

(This is for an assignment. One of my classmates recommended this site to get some help and my teacher is pretty chill about looking for answers from different sites.)

Edit: I finished the code but am getting some errors.
Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
./BankAccount.java:32: error: <identifier> expected
        public BankAccount(String[])
                                   ^
./BankAccount.java:24: error: constructor BankAccount(double) is already defined in class BankAccount
        public BankAccount(double userBalance)
               ^
Main.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        account1 balance = 1200;
        ^
  symbol:   class account1
  location: class Main
./BankAccount.java:69: error: cannot find symbol
            balance = userBalance;
                      ^
  symbol:   variable userBalance
  location: class BankAccount
4 errors
```

Comment: This is pretty basic Java, I would suggest looking into how methods and method signatures work.

Comment: Public void withdrawal(double amount) { balance -= amount; }  This would need error checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a method, you must have a ***return*** type. It should be **after the **access modifier**** and **before the method name**.

For clarifications, **void** is a return type that indicates that your method isn't required to return a data. (Implicitly, it just returns null)

From your instance, you can have the following method to add the value of the parameter `depositAmount` to the global variable `balance`:

```
public void deposit(double depositAmount) {
    balance += depositAmount;
}
```

From your example, you don't need to declare the variable type (*double*) again because it was already declared on the parameter.

For your other requirement, you can have the following method to deposit an array of depositAmounts in String:

```
public void deposit(String [] depositAmounts) {
    for (int i = 0; i < depositAmounts.length; i++) {
        balance += Double.parseDouble(depositAmounts[i]);
    }
}
```

To create a withdrawal method you can have the following method:

```
public void withdraw(double withdrawAmount) {
    balance -= withdrawAmount;
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to continue as follows:

```
public void withdraw(double amount) {
    balance -= amount;
}
```

The method withdraw is of a void return type, which means it does not return anything. If you would like it to return a balance, you'd need to type double instead of void and add a return value (return balance;). It's not neccesary or needed of course, I'm just pointing out the distinction of what void means.

As it stands, the code above will take in one argument - amount to be withdrawn - and subtracts that amount from the balance.